# Inject global variable accross all templates

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I wanted to ask, if there is a possibility to add a global variable like `sf_params` or `sf_data`, `sf_user`, `sf_context` or is there any possibility to extend one of those?

I want to change some application params within runtime (in partials, templates and actions).
Now sf docs suggest to use something like `app.yml`, but my problem is, that I need to execute a bit of code before setting this params. So they need to be setted very dynamically, which isn't that possible with `app.yml`.

Anyone of you got some suggestions how to implement a new global var or global object into symfony which is accessible from almost everywhere in the project?

Comment: by 'almost everywhere' do you mean you want access from Models and Views too?

Comment: Could you describe which kind of action you want to perform on this _global variable_ and where ?

Comment: my all project configuration data saved in Database what i want to do is creating a singleton class that will fetch all data from database inside constructor and set as object property so any time i want config values then i can pull from singleton object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the solution from @olivierw.

For a personal project, I have a table called `Config` and I load the content using filter, so I can have access anywhere in my project.

The filter `lib/filter/configFilter.php`:

```
<?php

class configFilter extends sfFilter
{
  public function execute ($filterChain)
  {
    // get the config
    $configs = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Config')>findAll();

    foreach($configs as $config)
    {
      sfConfig::set('my_config_'.$config->getName(), $config->getContent());
    }

    // execute next filter
    $filterChain->execute();
  }
}
```

In `apps/frontend/config/filters.yml`:

```yml
rendering: ~

configFilter:
  class: configFilter

security:  ~
```

Now you can access any information using:

```
sfConfig::get('my_config_key');
```

The `schema.yml` for my `Config` table:

```yml
Config:
  columns:
    name:     { type: string(255) }
    content:  { type: string(1000) }
```

Answer (score 2):

The best place where to store the configuration data is in the `sfConfig` object which is available in any part of your project. So you have to query your database for your configuration data and populate the sfConfig object via `sfConfig::set('variableName', $value)`. So:

1. create a static class which will query the database and populate the `sfConfig` object,
2. Add a filter which will call this class to execute its job at any request.